# retrieve the image through image src url in gwt

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, gxt

I am working on GWT and the following is my code:

```
  if(rs1.next()){
    int len = imgLen.length();
    byte [] rb = new byte[len];

    InputStream readImg = rs1.getBinaryStream(1);

    int index=readImg.read(rb, 0, len);
    System.out.println("hello");
    System.out.println("index"+index);
    //st.close();
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("image/png");

    System.out.println("response"+response);

    int len3 = 0;

    while ((len = readImg.read(rb)) != -1) {
              response.getOutputStream().write(rb,0,len);
              System.out.println( response);
    }
```

I use this code to retrieve the image from mySQL database at server side. Its response at client side is "**IMG src="http://some path:8888/m/upload**" url. So does anybody know how to retrieve the image at client side?

Answer (score 2):

The question is not GWT specific per say. It looks like you have images stored in your datase and you want to make them available to a web page (in your case the client side of your GWT application).

1. create a servlet that accepts the image id or whatever as a parameter, reads the image from the database and writes it out to the response.getOutputStream (it looks like you have that code already, just put it in a standalone servlet).
2. give a path to your image servlet in web.xml
   for example servlet mapping is /db-images
3. your images stored in the database are now accessible at http://your-server/your-app-context/db-images?id=123

Comment: sir , response.getOutputStream () my response return server to client as http://localhost:8080/m/war/images/imagename?id=123 their m is my project name and in war i create a folder images where image is stored in local system in war/images.....    at client side i give image m=new images m.seturl(responsetext) ...responsetext give the url at client side but image nt shown ...is m doing right

Answer (score 0):

Well you could be a little more precise at asking your question. But from what I understand you're trying to display an image from a URL? Maybe this will help.

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Image.html

Comment: For GWT 2.2 : http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Image.html